# Report filters not showing up

Tags: reporting

There is an issue which is troubling me. There are 2 people whose role is Marketing admin, who share the same profile. There Is a report which needs to be viewed by both of these people. X can see all the report filters on the report, where as Y can only see few of the filters. Have you guys faced such a situation.? If so could you let me know the reason for Y not able to see all the report filters as X.?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is Field Level Security. While the profiles may appear identical, if you check the FLS for both profiles, you'll likely find that one doesn't have the ability to view some of the fields. This will cause the report to behave differently, including missing filters and, as a consequence, more records may appear for the user with access to fewer fields.

Comment: They both have the same profile, Marketing ops Admin. I am sorry I mentioned as Identical.

Comment: are there any permission sets assigned to the one user that can see more values? to correct the issue (if you haven't already looked at this), if they're both the same profile, i'd make sure that the fields that are listed as filters in the report are indeed selected as visible in the profile object settings.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Partner Communities and one of those two people is a Partner Community User, it is quite well possible, that despite having the same profile, they do not see all the same fields and thus filters.
One example which causes this behaviour:

- Create custom Report Type over Opportunity
- Create a Report with that Report Type and set the filter for Opportunity Owner
- Your Partner Community user will not see that field and thus the filter while your standard license user will

Salesforce's official help will suggest using a standard report type which does not have said limitation.